# What device to use to chop/dice tomatoes?

Tags: equipment, tomatoes

I make chunky salsa in 2 quart batches. I have terrible knife skills, it takes me way too long to dice the amount of tomatoes needed for a batch. I am looking for a piece of equipment that will chop or dice the tomatoes into appox. 1/4 inch pieces in a quick and efficient manner.

Answer (score 1):

Working as a cook myself... unless you really like chunky I would go with a blender. Issue with a blender about half the tomatoes will be a purree before you get rid of all the big chunks and if you start cutting up the tomatoes it wont take all that much longer just to dice em..

Blender quick but half will be a purree ?
Dicing  all of it will be nice even dice but takes longer.
Which is more important nice and chunky or speed?

Comment: Tried this it was "okay" It was faster than dicing by hand, but to get a decent consistency I can only do 1 or 2 tomatoes at a time. I'm thinking a food processor might be my best bet.

Answer (score 1):

I cut the things in thick slices and put them through a [french fry cutter](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22french%20fry%20cutter%22&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=1uNyVZbOHcbToASUy4HoBA&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg&biw=1014&bih=562).
That gives me nice tomato cubes without much hassle.

Incidentally, the cutter works great on peppers, bell etc, too; nice square bits, little effort; plus of course you can make french fries or cottage fries.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar to [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Kenwood-Electric-Chopper-Processor-Vegetables/dp/B00PWSOKEM). The size of the pieces it chops into just depends on how long you run it - the longer you run it, the smaller the pieces.